# How can I use Mutiny unis in a vertx router handler?

Tags: vert.x, mutiny

While this returns a HTTP response body containing "hello"

```java
    router.get("/").respond(rc -> 
      Uni.createFrom().item("hello")
    );
```

this does not

```java
    router
      .get("/hello")
      .handler(context ->
        Uni.createFrom().item("hello")
          .subscribe()
          .with(item -> context.end(item))
      );
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RoutingContext#end(java.lang.String)](https://smallrye.io/smallrye-mutiny-vertx-bindings/3.1.0/apidocs/io/vertx/mutiny/ext/web/RoutingContext.html#end(java.lang.String)) returns a `Uni`, which is lazy. If you don't subscribe to it, nothing happens.

If you don't care about the result, use [RoutingContext#endAndForget(java.lang.String)](https://smallrye.io/smallrye-mutiny-vertx-bindings/3.1.0/apidocs/io/vertx/mutiny/ext/web/RoutingContext.html#endAndForget()) instead:

```
router
      .get("/hello")
      .handler(context ->
        Uni.createFrom().item("hello")
          .subscribe()
          .with(item -> context.endAndForget(item))
      );
```

Comment: oh boy... i did not check that RoutingContext.end() returns itself a Uni